Search for C1 control characters in SQL Server
I have a tables in SQL Server and some of the values in the varchar column contain C1 control characters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#STX
When I copy the value into notepad++, I get:

and when I read in python, I get 'Tylerâ\x80\x99s way'
I can remove \x80\x99 and write back to SQL, but this causes downstream issues, as the values are not the same.
I would thus like to search for the \x80\x99 in the varchar column and replace, but running this query
select * from tableName where AddressLine2 like  '%\x80%'

return 0 rows, when I know there should be 49 rows - see apostrophe-like character appears in DataFrame as 'â\x80\x99'
How can I search for this specific character, as https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6022/sql-server-char-function-and-reference-guide/ does not show the correct char() mapping
EDIT:
I inherited a table, and am trying to find a way to work with it. Original text may have been Tyler's way, but for some reason in SQL there are \x80\x99 characters, which according to notepad++ are PAD and SGCI characters.
Searching for char(0x80) finds the €, not the PAD char that is in Tylerâ\x80\x99s way, and when searching, returns the incorrect results
I guess what is the SQL char mapping that maps to the padding character
Edit2:
Tried searching for specific characters in the queries, but did not pick up the PAD or SGCI character. These 2 extra searches did not find what I was looking for, but did pick up the TM and Euro symbols
select AddressLine2 from tablename a
where a.id = 1482786

select AddressLine2 from tablename a
where AddressLine2 like '%' + char(0x99) + '%'

select AddressLine2 from tablename a
where AddressLine2 like '%' + char(0x80) + '%'



'%\x80%' is looking for the literal value '\x80' not the encoded character value for the hex value 0x80. You could use CHAR(0x80) for the character though.

Weren't you asking about this yesterday? The original text was Tyler’s way with a U+2019 Right Single Quotation Mark. You need to fix the character encoding in Python before inserting it into SQL Server or, alternatively, use a UTF-8 collation in the data table's column so that SQL Server understands that it's UTF-8 encoding and deals with it appropriately.

As a side note in ASCII, which your SQL is presumably using, 0x80 is a Euro Sign (€) and 0x99 is a trademark symbol (™). Neither of those are control characters. So you could just do WHERE AddressLine2 LIKE '%€%'. Sounds like, as @AlwaysLearning alludes to, you aren't using "UTF-8 the whole way through" but expect characters to be the same; ASCII and UTF-8 are very different.

question updated based on the comments

"Original text may have been Tyler's way" It wasn't, per your prior question, it was Tyler’s way; ’ <> '. You are then inserted that value, which appears to be UTF-8 encoded, into an ASCII encoded varchar. ’ in UTF-8 is 0xE28099, however, in ASCII, that is â€™, which is what you have in the database. The problem is, again, you are switching encoding; you should most likely be using an nvarchar in SQL Server.

"which according to notepad++ are PAD and SGCI characters." They are, in UTF-8, but your SQL Server isn't using UTF-8, it's using ASCII. If you tell NOtepad++ the encoding of the text is ASCII, you'll get â€™.

@ThomA as a side note, in ASCII 0x80 has no meaning. ASCII only defines the 7 bit character codes from 0x00 - 0x7F.

Fine, to nitpic "Windows 1252" @AlwaysLearning ... The point is the same, UTF-8 <> Whatever code page the OP is using in SQL Server.

I'm no unicode wiz like the other guys, but what's wrong with just replace(addressline2, 'â€™', '''')
